# Traceview shows some methods arent being called for 200ms or more

Tags: java, android

Traceview shows that updatePhysics() is being called every 10ms or so and it takes about 8ms to run. The methods that I call inside updatePhysics are only running once every 5 or 6 times updatePhysics() runs, however. Is this simply a bug of Traceview, or what is going on? My game is stuttering a fair amount, so I am trying to figure out what is causing it.

Traceview is generally showing that a lot of my methods go several hundred milliseconds without being called once, even though there appears to be no reason they shouldnt be called. Ideas?

Run Method:

```
        while (mRun) 
        {
            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
            Canvas c = null;
            try 
            {
                c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);//null
                {
                    time2 = System.nanoTime()/100000; // Get current time
                    float delta = (time2 - time1)/1000f;

                    if (mMode == STATE_RUNNING) updatePhysics(delta);
                    else updateMenus();
                    doDraw(c);
                    time1 = time2;
                }
            } finally
            {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (c != null) 
                {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
```

Update Physics:

```
    private void updatePhysics(float delta)
    {
        updateScore(delta);
        updateDifficulty();
    }
```

EDIT: As you can see here, updateDifficulty is often not called for several hundred ms EVEN THOUGH updatePhysics is being called regularly... It makes no sense. [Screenshot of traceview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU6Fv.png)

Comment: Well your updatephysics function doesn't take any parameters while the function you call in your thread includes a parameter. Also, you shouldn't rely on your methods being called that fast. You have no control over the OS scheduling.

Comment: Ah, that was just me copying the text wrong into this window. Ok, if people have no control over how often methods are called, and it is perfectly acceptable for delays of several hundred ms, how do games run smoothly?!?

Comment: Have you read through the guides on responsiveness, performance, etc in the dev guide? http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html  One of the big things is to avoid memory allocations (so you can avoid gc's).  Also, don't do anything time consuming (like calculating physics) in the UI thread as this can block the update of the UI.

Comment: Hmm, I am calling updatePhysics() from my run loop in my surfaceview thread. Would that count as teh UI thread? If so, how could I avoid doing that? And yeah, I don't allocate any memory during runtime, I almost never have GC's.

Comment: Hmm, the traceview looks ok to me - you have 343 calls of updatePhysics and 343 calls of updateDifficulty. It is just a feeling, but what happens if you move the setPriority line to before the while loop starts?

Comment: `I don't allocate any memory during runtime` That's impossible in java.

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice that, sigh. I moved the setPriority line out of the loop but it sadly makes no difference. In that case, if there are an identical number of calls of each, why would there not always be a small line drawn above each 'updatePhysics' block to indicate updateDifficulty has run? EDIT: It is not impossible to not allocate memory that is garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely somewhere in your thread you're calling thread.Sleep(0) or thread.Yield() or something like that. This will cause a thread to yield to other threads that are being scheduled. And it will often take 10ms or more before the thread gets scheduled back in. I think traceview doesn't understand this fully and counts the time the thread is in suspended state as being active.

Most games use a constant game loop, a real while(true) that never yields to anything.

Some other comments:

I would try the code without the try-catch block, this will slow things down considerabely. Als remove the threadpriority line, this is an OS call and could be slow, and would not add any speed in case of a bug. (It should be fine on normal priority)

Also are you sure this is correct:

```
time2 = System.nanoTime()/100000; // Get current time
float delta = (time2 - time1)/1000f;
```

I don't see why you require to devide the delta and the current time. Either convert the time from nanotime to seconds (or whatever you require), and then have a delta in seconds. Or keep time in nanoseconds and convert the delta to seconds. Now you first convert to seconds and then to 1/1000th of a second.

Comment: Hmm, I think you are on the right track, but I removed all 'sleep' statements (and I have no yields), and I removed the try/catch from the run loop, and the threadpriority line, and removed the /1000f. Sadly it has made no noticeable difference to the stutter that occurs every 2/3 of a second or so. I have even tried just doing main.y+=5; each cycle, and interestingly that has just as much lag as main.y+=5*delta; so the delta isn't even doing anything beneficial. I am tempted to simply stip everything out of my game except the code needed to show the issue and upload the source...

Comment: Well I know that on WP7 C# has a non-generational garbage collector that stutters the game every few seconds if there is a lot of garbage generated. I'm not sure on Android/JAVA but it could be the same thing, as the Garbage collector would interrupt the program to clean stuff up. Can you extract GC data using your profiler? If this is the problem then try using pools of objects instead of newing objects all the time in critical areas.

Comment: Sadly it isn't the garbage collector, I have already eliminated that, i get garbage collections about once every 30 seconds to a minute now, whereas i get stuttering every second or so.

Comment: Hmm, well with the information we have now I can't help you further. Are you able to narrow it down a bit more or making a proof-case?

Comment: Hmm, I spent about two hours stripping down the lunarlander example and adding my simple scrolling background from my game. It would be awesome if you can take a quick look, I have tried to simplify it as much as possible so I don't waste your time. A stripped down lunarlander example is what I based my game off. This example stutters for about 1/10th of a second every second or so on my phone even when there is no GC. You can download the source here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4972001/LunarLander.rar

Comment: Hey Smills, I'd love to help, but I have no Android phone or emulator, all the tips I gave you where just tips for similar problems I've dealt with on the Xbox and WP7.

Comment: Ah blast, well you certainly seem to have a lot of experience. I actually have more experience with XNA than I have with android development myself. I will post it in a seperate question then I guess. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Ah yes I'm an XNA person myself :)