# Preventing "flickering" when calling Drawable.draw()

Tags: android, android-emulator, surfaceview

I have a little experimentation app (essentially a *very* cut-down version of the [LunarLander](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html) demo in the Android SDK), with a single `SurfaceView`.  I have a `Drawable` "sprite" which I periodically draw into the `SurfaceView`'s `Canvas` object in different locations, without attempting to erase the previous image.  Thus:

```
private class MyThread extends Thread {
    SurfaceHolder holder;  // Initialised in ctor (acquired via getHolder())
    Drawable      sprite;  // Initialised in ctor
    Rect          bounds;  // Initialised in ctor

    ...

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (bounds) {
                sprite.setBounds(bounds);
            }
            sprite.draw(c);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Periodically called from activity thread
     */
    public void updatePos(int dx, int dy) {
        synchronized (bounds) {
            bounds.offset(dx, dy);
        }
    }
}
```

Running in the emulator, what I'm seeing is that after a few updates have occurred, several old "copies" of the image begin to flicker, i.e. appearing and disappearing.  I initially assumed that perhaps I was misunderstanding the semantics of a `Canvas`, and that it somehow maintains "layers", and that I was thrashing it to death.  However, I then discovered that I only get this effect if I try to update faster than roughly every 200 ms.  So my next best theory is that this is perhaps an artifact of the emulator not being able to keep up, and tearing the display.  (I don't have a physical device to test on, yet.)

Is either of these theories correct?

*Note: I don't actually want to do this in practice (i.e. draw hundreds of overlaid copies of the same thing).  However, I would like to understand why this is happening.*

**Environment:**

- Eclipse 3.6.1 (Helios) on Windows 7
- JDK 6
- Android SDK Tools r9
- App is targetting Android 2.3.1

**Tangential question:**

My `run()` method is essentially a stripped-down version of how the LunarLander example works (with all the excess logic removed).  I don't quite understand why this isn't going to saturate the CPU, as there seems to be nothing to prevent it running at full pelt.  Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: Are you drawing to your Canvas on both threads? What clears away what you drew the previous frame? Doesn't that example have a background being drawn also?

Comment: @Reuben: No, just the above thread.  Nothing else is being drawn (I've stripped LunarLander down as far as possible as a learning exercise).  I'm intentionally not clearing the view in any way, in order to see what happens.

Comment: Try inserting a "c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);" before your sprite.draw() ?

Comment: @Rebuen: I know that that will give me a single copy of the sprite on the display at any one time (and indeed, that's what happens when I try it).  But that's not what I'm after; I want to display an ever-increasing number of copies of the sprite simultaneously, with each copy at a random location.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I've butchered Lunar Lander in a similar way to you, and having seen the flickering I can tell you that what you are seeing is a simple artefact of the double-buffering mechanism that every `Surface` has.

When you draw anything on a `Canvas` attached to a `Surface`, you are drawing to the 'back' buffer (the invisible one). And when you `unlockCanvasAndPost()` you are swapping the buffers over... what you drew suddenly becomes visible as the "back" buffer becomes the "front", and vice versa. And so your next frame of drawing is done to the old "front" buffer...

The point is that you always draw to seperate buffers on alternate frames. I guess there's an implicit assumption in graphics architecture that you're *always* going to be writing every pixel.

Having understood this, I think the real question is why doesn't it flicker on hardware? Having worked on graphics drivers in years gone by, I can guess at the reasons but hesitate to speculate too far. Hopefully the above will be sufficient to satisfy your curiousity about this rendering artefact. :-)

Comment: Thanks for investigating; this explanation does make quite a lot of sense!  However, where is the dependency on the "update" period coming from?  Why does the rate that I update the coordinates of the *upcoming* sprite affect the "flickering" of *old* copies?

Comment: You will only see flicker when the sequence through the CPU is update->draw->update. If there is more than one 'draw' between any two 'update's then that draw got drawn to both buffers, and hence you'll never see that particular draw flicker.

Comment: Since your rendering thread is running as fast as it can, your update frequency on the UI thread must be high enough to challenge it for CPU time and so enter the update->draw->update cycle that causes the flicker (cos only one buffer gets that particular write).

Comment: That does sound pretty convincing.  I'm going to try some experiments later; if they confirm your explanation, then you can have the bounty!

Comment: @Oli I suppose I shouldn't grumble at a half bounty, but... bah. :-\

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the previous position of the sprite, as well as the new position. This is what the View system does automatically. However, if you use a Surface directly and do not redraw every pixel (either with an opaque color or using a SRC blending mode) you must clear the content of the buffer yourself. Note that you can pass a dirty rectangle to lockCanvas() and it will do the union for you of the previous dirty rectangle and the one you are passing (this is the mechanism used by the UI toolkit.) It will also set the clip rect of the Canvas to be the union of these two rectangles.

As for your second question, unlockAndPost() will do a vsync, so you will never draw at more than ~60fps (most devices that I've seen have a display refresh rate set around 55Hz.)

Comment: Yes, I know that for any *normal* situation, I would want to blank the surface before drawing the next frame!  My situation isn't a realistic one; I'm simply trying to understand *why* I'm getting the effect I'm seeing.

Comment: Because like Reuben said above a Surface is double buffered, so you see the previous frame interlaced with the new ones you are drawing.